# Export only events from a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

As a part of a migration, I need to export MySQL events from a MySQL 5.6 cluster and import them in a MySQL 5.7 cluster

Is copying the table `mysql.event` enough for this or is there any better way to export only events from a MySQL database?

Comment: Do you mean some "events" table of your database or your cluster events log? For a database table you can export data with mysqldump or "select data ... outfile", or use some third-party backup tool.

Comment: I mean mysql "events" that you can see with SHOW EVENTS. I need to export events only, not other data. I'm not sure if just dumping `mysql.event` is enough to achieve that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried this:

```
mysqldump -A --no-data --no-create-info --skip-triggers --no-create-db \
   --events > just-events.sql
```

It seems to dump only events.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks!